# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500. React + Springboot (on Heroku)

Tags: база-данных, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, get

Здраствуйте, у меня возникла ошибка при get запросе
Код с spring-а:

```
@GetMapping("/patients/comments/{id}/{text}/{data}")
public void setPatientComment(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String text, @PathVariable 
String data) {

    patientService.setPatientComment(text, data, id);
}
```

Код с React:

```
saveComment(patientID, commentText, commentData) {
    axios.get(`${url}/patients/comments/${patientID}/${commentText}/${commentData}`)
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
        .then(() => {
            // always executed
        });
}
```

Скрин ошибки с локалки npm start:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот с Postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CORS был добавлен.
Если нужна дополнительная информация пишите, буду благодарен любой помощи
Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/theShaper-I/vitechBackend

Comment: Ошибка на сервере, могу только порекоммендовать поставить точки останова на бэке и продебажить. Так не понятно что и где ломается

Comment: До того пока не залил на Хероку все работало отлично, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0):

Неправильное название БД в запросе

@Query(value = "insert into ***comments*** (text, data, patient_id) VALUES (:text, :data, :id)", nativeQuery = true)
void setPatientComment(@Param("text") String text, @Param("data") String data, @Param("id") Long id);